# Can an enchantment creature with hexproof be targeted by destroy target enchantment card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can an enchantment creature with hexproof be targeted by a spell that destroys enchantments. For example, can [Archetype of Endurance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArchetype%20of%20Endurance%5d) be targeted by [Naturalize](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNaturalize%5d)?

Answer (score 5):

No. Hexproof prevents something from being targeted by opponents' spells and abilities — that's pretty final. You can't target Archetype of Endurance with Naturalize because you can't target it at all; there's nothing special about enchantment removal.

(If you're thinking hexproof is a creature thing, and we're getting around it by targeting their enchantment-enss instead of their creature-ness, that's not how things work in M:tG. Note also that anything can have hexproof: [enchantments](https://scryfall.com/card/ogw/57), [players](https://scryfall.com/card/c17/73), or even [every permanent you control](https://scryfall.com/search?q=re%3A%22permanents*have*hexproof%22).)

You get around this by doing things that don't target the creature: [Dead Drop](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDead%20Drop%5d), [Toxic Deluge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bToxic%20Deluge%5d), [Settle the Wreckage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSettle%20the%20Wreckage%5d), are examples of the kinds of non-targeting effects you'd use, or a plain old [Wrath of God](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWrath%20of%20God%5d) effect. Or kill it in combat.